# Prove or disprove that $(A\mathbin\%B)\mathbin\%C = (A\mathbin\%C)\mathbin\%B$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Prove or disprove that $(A\mathbin\%B)\mathbin\%C = (A\mathbin\%C)\mathbin\%B$

I am not able how to prove (or disprove by example ) that $(A\mathbin\%B)\mathbin\%C = (A\mathbin\%C)\mathbin\%B$?

where $\mathbin\% = $modulo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is clearly not true.

take $B$ and $C$ coprime integers larger than $1$.

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem there is a positive $A$ so that:

$A\equiv 0\bmod B$ and $A\equiv 1 \bmod C$

We then have:

$(A\mathbin\%B)\mathbin\%C=0\mathbin\%C=0$

$(A\mathbin\%C)\mathbin\%B=1\mathbin\%C=1$

A concrete case is:

$B=2,C=3,A=4$

Answer (score 1):

$A = 4, B = 3, C = 2$ is a counterexample, giving
$$
(A\mathbin\%B)\mathbin\%C = (4\mathbin\%3)\mathbin\%2 = 1\mathbin\%2 = 1\\
(A\mathbin\%C)\mathbin\%B = (4\mathbin\%2)\mathbin\%3 = 0\mathbin\%3 = 0
$$